# set of strings should not be at the left side of the first seen ;

Tags: javascript, regex

This string (`kwordSyntaxSearch`) should pass the condition:

```
( sdf sdf )
cout<<"abc";

return 0;
}
```

This `kwordSyntaxSearch` must not pass the condition:

```
( sdf sdf )
cout<<"abc"

return 0;
}
```

This is a modified condition from the answer of username: f-j from my prev question but i realized i needed more help.This pass the 2nd block of code (w/c should not)

```
if( /^\s*\([\s\S]*\)\s*[^\{](?:(?![^\s\S]if|else|elseif|for|while|do|switch|\}|return)|[\s\S]*);/.test(kwordSyntaxSearch)
```

I wanted to pass the condition if the first `;` has not seen any of `if,else,else if,for, while,do,switch,},return` before it (on its left side)

Can you please help me adjust the code so that it would pass the first block and not the 2nd block.

Comment: Are you sure you can do the whole sytax checking using regular expressions? It seems you are implementing some kind of domain specific language. Perhaps you should consider using a parser generator, e.g. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: this is for c++ beginners, a system that will simulate variable's value. this is the hardest part i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lookahead part seems slightly wrong. Disregarding the long alternation, yours has the structure

```
(?:(?!...)|[\s\S]*)
```

For one thing the lookahead is completely optional and cannot even get you anywhere, because it consumes no characters - so it's never even used. Then, even if you remove the `|` you only check the condition once, and then match away at the `[\s\S]*`. You need to pull the `*` outside the non-capturing group, so that the condition is checked at every single position, like so:

```
(?:(?!...)[\s\S])*
```

This is a really common pattern to emulate `[^a]*` where you want to exclude something more complex then a single character `a`. So, your full pattern would look like

```
^\s*\([\s\S]*\)\s*[^\{](?:(?!if|else|elseif|for|while|do|switch|\}|return)[\s\S])*;
```

or

```
^\s*\([^]*\)\s*[^{](?:(?!if|else|elseif|for|while|do|switch|}|return)[^])*;
```

Note that I also removed the `[^\s\S]`, because it cannot match - anything - ever.

Comment: is ^ exactly equivalent to \s\S?

Comment: when do exactly do i place \b so that if the string contain 'switcher' it would not be a problem

Comment: @fireflieslive first question, no but `[^]` is (in JS) exactly equivalent to `[\s\S]`. you use `\b` around the words. like `\bswitch\b`. To do that for all of your words, you could use `(?!\b(?:if|else|...)\b)`.